# Alternative to "Load" listener in order to load HTMLcollection elements

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, tampermonkey, htmlcollection

I am using Tampermonkey to run some JavaScript on a webpage.

I am using `x = document.getElementsByClassName("class")` because I need the length and the elements of `x`; but in the last weeks, the old code did not work, so I had to change it and add a "load" event listener (Before it worked without the event listener line):

```js
x = document.getElementsByClassName(" class ");

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  sw = x.length; //(length of x is always between 0 and 4)
  switch (sw) {
    case 1:
      //do something with x[0] and reload after timeout;
      break;
    case 2:
      //do something with x[0] x[1] and reload after timeout
      break;
    case 3:
      //do something with x[0] x[1] x[2] and reload after timeout
      break;
    case 4:
      //do something with x[0] x[1] x[2] x[3] and reload after timeout
      break;
    default:
      setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
      }, RandomReloadTime * 1000);
      break;
  }
});
```

I need this to be running all the time, so my issue is that when the tab is not active (usually during the night when I sleep, PC on, tab opened, but Chrome puts the tab to 'sleep'), the webpage is not loaded, hence the listener is not activated;

To summarize, what I want to do is (using Tampermonkey):

- Add elements of that class to `X`.
- Use elements added in `X` and reload to do it all over again

Is there another way in which I can do this?

Comment: If you type chrome://discards/ in the Chrome address line you can disable "Auto Discardable" for that tab, this means Chrome will only put the tab to sleep if memory is low. I believe there is also an option somewhere to disable it for all tabs.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try; I looked into flags, as that was the way it worked before, but could not find anything; did not know they added Discards. Meanwhile, if there is an alternative to using eventlisteners in order to access elements from HTML collection, I would also be interested in that

Comment: I have tried setting the tab to discard, but it did not help. because the page was not loaded, hence the listener was not activated; I think chrome does not load if it is not in the main/active tab even if I refresh it from the script; at the moment I did not manage to find any workaround, or at least an event listener that is always active on the page

Comment: I don't think the event listener is the problem. Once the tab is sleeping, then the user script is never executed. You need to find a way to prevent Chrome from putting the tab into sleep. Maybe playing an audio/video in an endless loop in the tab can prevent Chrome from putting the tab to sleep. Or you could check if other browser don't do it.For example Firefox also supports Tampermonkey

Comment: At the moment I have a workaround, I use an auto clicker to keep the webpage alive; but soon I will need to run the script on multiple tabs, and I cannot keep them all alive. 
The script is always run on the webpage, but since the page is not loaded, the "Load" event listener is not activated and the code under it is not executed. I also tried to run the script without the event listener, but in this case I could not access the elements from the HTML collection

Comment: If the script is executed, you can just continuously check whether the elements are there, for example check every second like this:  setInterval(function() { x = document.getElementsByClassName("class"); sw = x.length; switch(..... }, 1000)

Comment: I have tried an alternative with 
$( document ).ready(function() { ... }
instead of 
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) { ... }

and until now it is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `window.addEventListener("load", function(event) { ... }` with `$( document ).ready(function() { ... }` , the script behaved as I expected.

Apparently, I did not need the whole page to be loaded in order to use elements from the DOM, just the DOM needed to be loadedl and that can be done with the second command. The difference is best explained [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
> jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
> $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
> Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
> inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the
> entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.